# disable an Item In the list View !

Tags: android, android-listview

I have read your solution to disable an Item in a List Activity in this link 
[Android: How to disable list items on list creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation).
But when i tested your solution, it works fine, the item wanted is disabled, but the separator 
of the list is gone.
Do you Have an issue for this problem ??

Comment: This seems to be referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation/2553338#2553338

Comment: @Mark Booth: Yes, I've edited in the link to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override areAllItemsEnabled().

Comment: Nothing changed. Why did you suggest this?