# How do I make this listview unselectable?

Tags: android

I want to make a listview unselectable and unclickable. I'm talking about the color change that occurs when I click on a list item. The code is given below. I'm a newbie in android so please be kind.

from : listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="8px">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

from : details.java

```
TestActionAdapter() {
        super(TestDetails.this, R.layout.action_list_item, actions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TestAction action = actions.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(action.getLabel());
        TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
        data.setText(action.getData());
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the answer here:

[How to disable list items...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation)

Basically extend `ArrayAdapter`, and add these 2 functions:

```
 @Override
 public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
     return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: But the separator between items have disappeared now. Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: Overriding the areAllItemsEnabled() method seems to remove the list view dividers, so only override isEnabled(int position) if you want to keep your dividers.

Comment: how to do it with `BaseAdapter`

Answer (score 10):

If all you want is to prevent all rows highlighting on click just use `ListView android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

When you return view from `getView(..)` Method, just put in `view.setEnabled(false)` before `return view` .

Comment: I tried it but the color changes to white still when i click on the item.