# How to make a ListView unselectable on a Button press

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a listview and a button. Only when I press the button I want the entire ListView to be unselectable.
My ListView is a collection of checkboxes and I want to prevent change in the state of checkboxes when I press the button so I want to disable the listView.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation

Comment: I tried all these but even when i Override all methods to return false, after clicking the button it still allows me to change the ListView checkbox states

Comment: could  show some code about the Adapter ?and the button your want to disable?